# Optimize search to find next matching value in a list

Tags: python, bigdata

I have a program that goes through a list and for each objects finds the next instance that has a matching value. When it does it prints out the location of each objects. The program runs perfectly fine but the trouble I am running into is when I run it with a large volume of data (~6,000,000 objects in the list) it will take much too long. If anyone could provide insight into how I can make the process more efficient, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
def search(list):
    original = list
    matchedvalues = []
    count = 0
    for x in original:
        targetValue = x.getValue()
        count = count + 1
        copy = original[count:]
        for y in copy:
             if (targetValue == y.getValue):
                 print (str(x.getLocation) + (,) + str(y.getLocation))
                 break
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code by replacing all tabs with spaces.

Comment: You code seems imcompelte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can make a dictionary that contains a list of indexes that correspond to each item, something like this:

```
values = [1,2,3,1,2,3,4]

from collections import defaultdict

def get_matches(x):
    my_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for ind, ele in enumerate(x):
        my_dict[ele].append(ind)
    return my_dict
```

Result:

```
>>> get_matches(values)
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [0, 3], 2: [1, 4], 3: [2, 5], 4: [6]})
```

Edit:

I added this part, in case it helps:

```
values = [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,3]

def get_next_item_ind(x, ind):
    my_dict = get_matches(x)
    indexes = my_dict[x[ind]]
    temp_ind = indexes.index(ind)
    if len(indexes) > temp_ind + 1:
        return(indexes)[temp_ind + 1]
    return None
```

Result:

```
>>> get_next_item_ind(values, 0)
1
>>> get_next_item_ind(values, 1)
2
>>> get_next_item_ind(values, 2)
3
>>> get_next_item_ind(values, 3)
>>> get_next_item_ind(values, 4)
5
>>> get_next_item_ind(values, 5)
>>> get_next_item_ind(values, 6)
9
>>> get_next_item_ind(values, 7)
>>> get_next_item_ind(values, 8)
```

Comment: What if there are more than one matching items in the list? For example, what if values = [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,3]. Would your code still match it with the very next matching object in the list?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you could increase the efficiency of this search by minimising additional memory use (particularly when your data is BIG).

- you can operate directly on the list you are passing in, and don't need to make copies of it, in this way you won't need:  `original = list`, or `copy = original[count:]`
- you can use slices of the original list to test against, and `enumerate(p)` to iterate through these slices. You won't need the extra variable `count` and, `enumerate(p)` is efficient in Python

Re-implemented, this would become:

```
def search(p):
    # iterate over p
    for i, value in enumerate(p):

        # if value occurs more than once, print locations
        # do not re-test values that have already been tested (if value not in p[:i])
        if value not in p[:i] and value in p[(i + 1):]:
            print(e, ':', i, p[(i + 1):].index(e))

v = [1,2,3,1,2,3,4]

search(v)

1 : 0 2
2 : 1 2
3 : 2 2
```

Implementing it this way will only print out the values / locations where a value is repeated (which I think is what you intended in your original implementation).

Other considerations:

- *More than 2 occurrences of value:*    If the value repeats many times in the list, then you might want to implement a function to walk recursively through the list. As it is, the question doesn't address this - and it may be that it doesn't need to in your situation.
- *using a dictionary:* I completely agree with Akavall above, dictionary's are a great way of looking up values in Python - especially if you need to lookup values again later in the program. This will work best if you construct a dictionary instead of a list when you originally create the list. But if you are only doing this once, it is going to cost you more time to construct the dictionary and query over it than simply iterating over the list as described above.

Hope this helps!